# Permutations of an array where elements are repeated a certain number of times

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write an `Array` extension that does something like this:

I call it like this:

`%w[eggs bacon sausage].with_every_possibiity_of_multiples(2)`

And it gives me these:

```
  [   
    %w[eggs, bacon, sausage],
    %w[eggs, eggs, bacon, sausage],
    %w[eggs, bacon, bacon, sausage],
    %w[eggs, bacon, sausage, sausage],
    %w[eggs, eggs, bacon, bacon, sausage],
    %w[eggs, eggs, bacon, bacon, sausage, sausage],
  ]
```

Hopefully it's clear what's going on here. If I had called it with an argument of 3 instead of 2, I'd have gotten an array of 9 elements, one of them being `%w[eggs, eggs, eggs, bacon, sausage]`.

I'm struggling to come up with how to write this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Some thing wrong in your 'with_every_posssibiity_of_multiples(arg)' method. Post that method code

Comment: BTW, *permutation* is the wrong term; *combination* is closer

Comment: -1. Your question is not clear. I cannot get the rule. Why are ` %w[eggs, bacon, bacon, sausage, sausage]` and ` %w[eggs, eggs, bacon, sausage, sausage]` not in the array? In the first place, why do you have commas inside the `%w` notation?

Comment: Sorry, guys. I'm having a retarded day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sawa points out, you probably have your results mixed up. I'm guessing passing 2 gets you 8 elements, not 6, and passing 3 gets you 27, not 9.

You can make good use of [`Array#repeated_combination`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-repeated_combination) to generate the number of times you want to repeat each element:

```
class Array
  def with_every_possibility_of_multiples(n)
    (1..n).to_a.repeated_permutation(size).map do |repeats|
      zip(repeats).flat_map{|elem, nb| [elem] * nb}
    end
  end
end

food = %w[eggs bacon sausage]
food.with_every_possibility_of_multiples(2) # =>
[["eggs", "bacon", "sausage"], ["eggs", "bacon", "sausage", "sausage"], ["eggs", "bacon", "bacon", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "bacon", "bacon", "sausage", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "eggs", "bacon", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "eggs", "bacon", "sausage", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "eggs", "bacon", "bacon", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "eggs", "bacon", "bacon", "sausage", "sausage"]]

food.with_every_possibility_of_multiples(3) # =>
[["eggs", "bacon", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "bacon", "sausage", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "bacon", "sausage", "sausage", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "bacon", "bacon", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "bacon", "bacon", "sausage", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "bacon", "bacon", "sausage", "sausage", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "bacon", "bacon", "bacon", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "bacon", "bacon", "bacon", "sausage", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "bacon", "bacon", "bacon", "sausage", "sausage", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "eggs", "bacon", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "eggs", "bacon", "sausage", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "eggs", "bacon", "sausage", "sausage", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "eggs", "bacon", "bacon", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "eggs", "bacon", "bacon", "sausage", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "eggs", "bacon", "bacon", "sausage", "sausage", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "eggs", "bacon", "bacon", "bacon", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "eggs", "bacon", "bacon", "bacon", "sausage", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "eggs", "bacon", "bacon", "bacon", "sausage", "sausage", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "eggs", "eggs", "bacon", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "eggs", "eggs", "bacon", "sausage", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "eggs", "eggs", "bacon", "sausage", "sausage", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "eggs", "eggs", "bacon", "bacon", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "eggs", "eggs", "bacon", "bacon", "sausage", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "eggs", "eggs", "bacon", "bacon", "sausage", "sausage", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "eggs", "eggs", "bacon", "bacon", "bacon", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "eggs", "eggs", "bacon", "bacon", "bacon", "sausage", "sausage"],
 ["eggs", "eggs", "eggs", "bacon", "bacon", "bacon", "sausage", "sausage", "sausage"]]
```

Note that `repeated_permutation` is new to Ruby 1.9.2. You can `require 'backports'` in earlier versions, or use an uglier version using `product`:

```
# ...
(1..n).to_a.product(*[(1..n).to_a] * (size-1)).map do |repeats|
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this built-in permutation method:

```
   %w[eggs bacon sausage].permutation(2).to_a
```